# Unable to add Ubuntu CUPS printserver to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, network-printer, cups, print-server

I am trying to add a local port on Windows 10 machine for a virtual queue printer that installed on Ubuntu server.

When I enter `\\ip address for ubuntu server\name of printer`, I get the following error message: `The user name or password is incorrect`

I have checked that the virtual printer is shared and on CUPS setting I allowed all access to the printer.

Do you have any idea for this issue?

Comment: You'll need to enable IPP and add the printer via http as described [here](https://zedt.eu/tech/windows/installing-an-ipp-printer-in-windows-10/)

Comment: @mashuptwice Thank you for your comment, as you advised I can add the printer. However do you know why it does not work anymore? I used to add ldp printer by adding local port